# Sequelize.op is not defined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sequelize.js

I'm using sequelize with Node.js. I'm trying to use Sequelize.op request. But it doesn't work, this is my code :

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const Op = Sequelize.Op;
const operatorsAliases = {
$eq: Op.eq
}
```

This is the error in the node console :

[image]

Do you have any idea ?

Thank you

Comment: That error does not correspond to the provided piece of code.

Your snippet contains ne while error says about eq

Comment: What version of Sequelize do you have? If it is v3,  you can use this docs: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/v3/docs/docs/querying.md

Comment: @RafalWiliński There is a property "eq", look at the code carefully.

Answer (score 19):

**Last version for now:**

```
4.22.2
```

**models/user.js:**

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const op = Sequelize.Op;
const operatorsAliases = {
    $eq: op.eq,
    $or: op.or,
}

module.exports = function(sequelize) {

    var User = sequelize.define('user', {
        id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
        email: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
        username: { type: Sequelize.STRING(120) },
        ...
    });

    User.beforeCreate((user, options) => {
        var where = {
            type: 1,
            deleted: null, 
            // With aliases
            $or: [{email: {$eq: user.email} }, { username: {$eq: user.username}}]
            // Without aliases: Last version
            //[op.or]: [ { email: user.email }, { username: user.username } ]
        };

        return User.findOne({ where: where })
            .then(userFound => {
                ...  
            })
            .catch(err => {
                ...
            });
    });
    ...
    return User;
};
```

Answer (score 16):

I found the solution, I updated the sequelize version via npm, and it's work. So the solution is

`npm i sequelize@4.13.5 --s`

Answer (score 9):

Or in ES5 >

```
import { Op } from "sequelize";
```

Comment: Cheerio, works with Typescript.

Answer (score 3):

I had to *downgrade*

My package.json specified `"sequelize":"latest"`

So my server installed sequelize `"version": "5.8.2"`

Apparently this version of Sequelize does *not* have `Sequelize.Op`; so you will see the error.

So I downgraded back to version `4.41.2`; I specified explicitly in my package.json `"sequelize":"4.41.2"`

Comment: In Sequelize 5 the Op aliases are already built in, so instead of getting the Op object and writing something like `Op.gte`, you just write `$gte` directly in the query.

Comment: here they have a code sample of v4 vs. v5 syntax https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/master/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md#sequelize

Answer (score 3):

I solved (upgrading from v 4.44.x to v 5.21.4) adding
`const { Op } = require("sequelize");`

Answer (score 1):

Just use Sequelize from models/index.js

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const models = require('models');

const Op = models.Sequelize.Op;
const operatorsAliases = {
    $eq: models.Sequelize.Op.eq
}
```